# Carving elements from XML (xmlstarlet,awk,perl..)

Tags: xml, perl, awk, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to carve out sections from hundreds of XML files.  The structure of the XML docs is similar to:

```
<document>
<nodes>
<node id=123>pages of txt</node>
<node id-=124>more example pages of txt and sub elements</node>
</nodes></document>
```

I'm just trying to extract all `<node>` elements. I have been trying to use xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c “/document/nodes”
```

The problem is that it only returns `</nodes>`.

I just need to extract the following examples:

```
<node id=123>pages of txt</node>
<node id-=124>more example pages of txt and sub elements</node>
```

Can anyone recommend a better option, tool or approach? Many thanks.

Comment: What output do you want exactly? From what you have written it sounds like you just need to remove `<document>` and `<nodes>` from either end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have your xpath wrong:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//node'
```

Also, valid XML required all attribute values to be quoted

```
<document>
<nodes>
<node id="123">pages of txt</node>
<node id="124">more example pages of txt and sub elements</node>
</nodes></document>
```

I've found this page gives lots of useful xpath examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx